# pdb file is not the pdb file that was used when this precompiled header was created, recreated the precompiled header

Tags: c++17, juce

I am using JUCE to create an audio plugin, and on first build, I received several of the following error.

C2859   C:\Users\ksa10\Desktop\LUX\LUX\Builds\VisualStudio2022\x64\Debug\Shared Code\LUX.pdb is not the pdb file that was used when this precompiled header was created, recreate the precompiled header.

I believe this is an repetition error with improper conditional compilation in the files automatically created by JUCE, but I have not found any answers yet. If it helps, all of my header files start with `#pragma once`.

I am new to c++ and completely self-taught, so go easy on me.